# Как установить в программе строго портретный режим, без поворотов?

Tags: android, libgdx

как сделать так, чтоб сцена(программа) всегда оставалась в портретном режиме? В манифесте прописал, но работает только для экрана настроек. Так же указал:

```
config.useGyroscope = false;
config.useAccelerometer = false;
```

и

```
setRequestedOrientation(ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_PORTRAIT);
```

### Всё равно поворачивается при наклоне.

**UPD. Не работало из за стороннего лаунчера. В стандартном все работает без проблем..**
Моя невнимательность..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

В манифесте на уровне для каждой `activity` установите `android:screenOrientation="portrait"`

Comment: установил, не помогло.

Comment: обновил. Вы так установили?

Comment: Могу ошибаться, но альбомных ориентаций две, а в вопросе спрашивается не только как ограничиться альбомными, но и как запретить перевороты.

Comment: Да, так же прописано.

Comment: android:screenOrientation="portrait"  при таком конфиге у вас никаких переворотов не будет

Comment: Ой, я попутал. Надо для каждой активити поставить в манифесте android:screenOrientation="portrait"

Comment: Поставлено, толку 0, )))

Comment: Нужно использовать метод  Input.Orientation в libgdx скорей всего.

Comment: А вы libgdx используете?

Comment: Да, удалил тег "Android", чтобы не было недопонимания...

Answer (score 0):

Пропишите в AndroidManifest.xml для каждой активности следующие строки:

```
android:configChanges="orientation"
android:screenOrientation="portrait"
```

Атрибут `android:configChanges="orientation"` сообщает о том, что активность должна следить за ориентацией также во время работы. Сюда можно передавать не только ориентацию экрана, но и клавиатуру и т.д.

[Подробнее в документации.](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/activity-element.html?hl=ru#config)